# Apache Spark Random Forest Classification on AWS EMR fails and causes errors: Allocation Failure, HeartbeatReceiver, YarnClusterScheduler, etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, classification, random-forest, amazon-emr

I recently got into Apache Spark on AWS. I have a dataset with 10 columns and 7 million rows but I cannot use the whole set because Spark cannot handle it. When I take more than 1.5 million lines it crashes on a single r4.16xlarge instance with 488 GB RAM with insufficient memory erros (which I can confirm observing it with top, the memory consumption rises up to 100%). But when I try to run it on a whole cluster with significantly more memory (4 / 488 = 1952 GB) it also fails. I am using the following parameters for starting the EMR step:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class randomforest --driver-memory 400G --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 8 --executor-memory 400g s3://spark-cluster-demo/randomforest_2.11-1.0.jar
```

This is the scala script inside the jar I am executing:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{RandomForestClassificationModel, RandomForestClassifier}
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{IndexToString, StringIndexer, VectorIndexer}

object randomforest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Cluster Test")            
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark Cluster Test").getOrCreate

    // Load and parse the data file, converting it to a DataFrame.
    val data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("s3://spark-cluster-demo/2004_4000000.txt")

    val maxCategories = 512
    val numTrees = 64
    val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto" // supported featureSubsetStrategy settings: auto, all, onethird, sqrt, log2
    val impurity = "gini"
    val maxDepth = 30
    val maxBins = 2048
    val maxMemoryInMB = 409600

    // Index labels, adding metadata to the label column.
    // Fit on whole dataset to include all labels in index.
    val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label").setOutputCol("indexedLabel").fit(data)
    // Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
    // Set maxCategories so features with > X distinct values are treated as continuous.
    val featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("indexedFeatures").setMaxCategories(maxCategories).fit(data)

    // Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing).
    val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

    // Train a RandomForest model.
    val rf = new RandomForestClassifier().setLabelCol("indexedLabel").setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures").setNumTrees(numTrees).setFeatureSubsetStrategy(featureSubsetStrategy).setImpurity(impurity).setMaxDepth(maxDepth).setMaxBins(maxBins).setMaxMemoryInMB(maxMemoryInMB)

    // Convert indexed labels back to original labels.
    val labelConverter = new IndexToString().setInputCol("prediction").setOutputCol("predictedLabel").setLabels(labelIndexer.labels)

    // Chain indexers and forest in a Pipeline.
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(labelIndexer, featureIndexer, rf, labelConverter))

    // Train model. This also runs the indexers.
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Training time: " + (t1 - t0) + " ns")

    // Make predictions.
    val predictions = model.transform(testData)

    // Select example rows to display.
    predictions.select("predictedLabel", "label", "features").show(5)

  }

}
```

The whole log is too big to post it here. I get various different errors and failures which I will list here. All of them accure dozens or hundreds times all over the place:

```
2018-11-26T09:38:35.392+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-11-26T09:38:35.392+0000: [ParNew: 559232K->36334K(629120K), 0.0217574 secs] 559232K->36334K(2027264K), 0.0218269 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]

18/11/26 10:24:37 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from ip-172-31-17-60.ec2.internal/172.31.17.60:45589
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1106)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/11/26 10:24:37 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from ip-172-31-17-60.ec2.internal/172.31.17.60:45589 is closed
18/11/26 10:24:37 ERROR OneForOneBlockFetcher: Failed while starting block fetches
18/11/26 10:24:42 ERROR RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks (after 1 retries)

18/11/26 10:22:29 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 2 with no recent heartbeats: 141885 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 2 on ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal: Executor heartbeat timed out after 141885 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 16.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 1079, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 141885 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 1067, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 141885 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 12.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 1075, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 141885 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 1063, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 141885 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 20.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 1083, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 141885 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 47.0 (TID 1071, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 141885 ms
18/11/26 10:22:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.1 in stage 47.0 (TID 1084, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2, partition 8, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8550 bytes)
18/11/26 10:22:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 20.1 in stage 47.0 (TID 1085, ip-172-31-26-87.ec2.internal, executor 2, partition 20, PROCESS_LOCAL, 8550 bytes)

18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_2 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_10 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_6 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_18 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_22 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_1 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_14 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_36_5 !
18/11/26 10:40:29 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(8, ip-172-31-26-192.ec2.internal, 43287, None)
18/11/26 10:40:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 8 successfully in removeExecutor
18/11/26 10:40:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor 8 added was in lost list earlier.
18/11/26 10:40:29 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 47.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 47.0 (TID 1117, ip-172-31-26-192.ec2.internal, executor 8): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 8 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 170206 ms
Driver stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 47.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 47.0 (TID 1117, ip-172-31-26-192.ec2.internal, executor 8): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 8 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 170206 ms
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1803)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1791)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1790)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1790)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2024)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1973)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1962)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:682)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:742)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap(PairRDDFunctions.scala:742)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.findBestSplits(RandomForest.scala:563)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.run(RandomForest.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.train(RandomForestClassifier.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.train(RandomForestClassifier.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:149)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableViewLike$Transformed$class.foreach(IterableViewLike.scala:44)
        at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$AbstractTransformed.foreach(SeqViewLike.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:149)
        at randomforest$.main(randomforest.scala:48)
        at randomforest.main(randomforest.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
```

Is something wrong with my configuration or is it impossible to use such a big dataset for RF?

Comment: The errors arise because your executors are dying. You need to identify the first executor that dies to see the error reported. I suspect it's a memory issue (it nearly always is) or maybe a disk problem if there is lots of shuffle data (r4.16xlarge is EBS only - have you allocated any disk space?). I'm noticing also that you do not explicitly allocate any memory for spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead. Please try to use something like `--executor-memory 200g --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=200g` and see if that helps.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thanks a lot for the quick response! Executor 2 was the first one to fail, does it have its own log? How can I get that? I used the 4 r4.16 instances in their default configuration and did not add any more disk space, is that what you mean by "allocated any disk space"? I will try out the memory overhead immediately. What is the difference between allocating the 400g directly to the executor or doing so as overhead?

Comment: Spark uses off-heap memory for various things and  `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` specifies the amount of off-heap memory to be allocated per executor (`executor-memory` specifies on-heap memory). Since Spark 2.x I have found that the need for off-heap memory has grown significantly and where I used to have a ratio of 1:4, I find that I now need more like 1:2 (you should experiment with this, once you have gotten it to work).

Comment: Oh, and in term of EBS, you need to explictily attach an EBS volume (disk) to your r4.16xlarge instance if you want any disk space :-)

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thanks! The new test just finished. I added the memoryOverhead (200g) and also increased the EBS volumes from 32 to 200gb but it failed again with the same problems. Executor 1 failed first. Can I somehow find out why exactly?

Comment: Log files are located on the individual executors. From the EMR Console, you should be able to see a link to the log files. Otherwise, you can log on to the executors and find the logs in something like `/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/`. Also are you monitoring the job with SparkUI? You should be able to see errors from the executors in the SparkUI as well. Also, monitor the YARN UI, as it will report unhealthy nodes (indicating disk issues).